# Identifying the files to which the following display statements will write

Tags: verilog

```
//File output with multi-channel descriptor
module test;

integer handle1,handle2,handle3; //file handles

//open files
initial
begin
   handle1 = $fopen("f1.out");
   handle2 = $fopen("f2.out"); 
   handle3 = $fopen("f3.out"); 
end

//Display statements to files
initial
begin
//File output with multi-channel descriptor
   #5;
   $fdisplay(4, "Display Statement # 1");
   $fdisplay(15, "Display Statement # 2");
   $fdisplay(6, "Display Statement # 3");
   $fdisplay(10, "Display Statement # 4");
   $fdisplay(0, "Display Statement # 5");
end
endmodule
```

I have been searching for a proper explanation for this problem. What I know is that I have to start with the first "initial" block  -

> initial
>       begin
>       handle1 = $fopen("f1.out"); //32'h 0000 0002
>       handle2 = $fopen("f2.out"); //32'h 0000 0004
>       handle3 = $fopen("f3.out"); //32'h 0000 0008
>       end

After this I have no idea how I would find the files to which those display statements will write.Need to know how to solve this kind of problem.Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a homework problem or other exercise. Do you have the Verilog language specification?

Answer (score 1):

Each call to `$fopen` returns a 32-bit **multi channel descriptor (mcd)**.

Per the Verilog LRM:

> The multichannel descriptor `mcd` is a 32 bit reg in which a single bit is set indicating which file is opened. The least significant bit (bit 0) of an mcd always refers to the standard output. Output is directed to two or more files opened with multichannel descriptors by bitwise OR-ing together their mcds and writing to the resultant value.

So after opening the 3 files in your example, you could direct output to more than one file by doing this:

```
$fdisplay(handle1 | handle2, "Write to f1.out and f2.out");
$fdisplay(handle1 | 32'h00000001, "Write to f1.out and stdout");
```

If you look at the values passed to `$fdisplay` in your question, you should be able to figure out which bits are set, and therefore which files (including stdout) will be written to.

Comment: I think it is worth noting that `$fopen("x");` returns a 32 bit mcd (multi-channel designator) but `$fopen("x", "r");` returns a 32 bit fd (file descriptor). You are limited to writing to 31 files with a mcd or 2147483644 (MSB is always set, 3 reserved codes) with fd.